# The correct use of "for the first time/the first time"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense

With what tense should we use "for the first time" and "the first time"?

I am confused, because some native speakers told me that I had to always use Present Perfect. But others say that it depends on the time I am talking about(Past -> Past Perfect. Present -> Present Perfect)

UPD: Here are some examples: *The first time he(had) tried pizza was in Italy.
He(had) tried pizza for the first time in Italy.*

Comment: Present perfect would be wrong: "he tried" is simple past tense; you don't seem to have any present perfect verbs in your examples.

Comment: @StuartF - Not necessarily wrong. _Jim took his girlfriend to the local pizzeria last week. He had tried pizza for the first time a few weeks earlier and had very much enjoyed it._